# Como mostrar uma imagem de carregamento enquanto o conteúdo do iframe é carregado?

Tags: iframe

Como mostrar uma imagem de carregamento enquanto o conteúdo do `iframe` é carregado?

Answer (score 3):

O grande problema é que o *iFrame* está em um contexto diferente do seu. Já adianto que isso poderá ser tortuoso, ou mesmo impossível, caso a *iFrame* contenha material de um domínio diferente da *frame* mãe.

Vou dar uma sugestão que utiliza jQuery, por conveniência e por ser uma biblioteca praticamente onipresente. Deixe-nos saber se jQuery não lhe serve.

Para acessar o conteúdo de uma *frame* filha, você pode usar o método [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) do jQuery. Da documentação:

> The .contents() method can also be used to get the content document of an iframe, if the iframe is on the same domain as the main page.

Exemplo:

```
$("idDaTuaIFrame").contents().find(".foo");
```

Para acessar conteúdo da *frame* mãe (caso seu código esteja na *iFrame*), você adiciona um parâmetro a mais na query, `parent.document`. Da seguinte forma:

```
$("#foo", parent.document); // você acaba de acessar o elemento de ID foo na frame mãe
```

Com base nisso, você pode inserir uma *gif* animada **antes** da iFrame carregar. Daí você elabora alguma lógica na *iFrame* ou na *frame* mãe que esconda ou elimine a *gif* animada **após** o evento de carga da página o *iFrame*.

Caso não possa mudar o código da *iFrame*, você também pode usar a função [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval) para ler o estado da *iFrame* (talvez procurar por algum elemento específico) de forma periódica, para saber se a página foi completamente carregada. Apenas note que essa alternativa é um tanto deselegante.

Boa sorte!

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o que você queira é algo nesse sentido:

http://lucasmoreira.com.br/2013/07/15/carregamento-da-pagina-com-loading/

Este artigo é bem didático. O que você vai ter que fazer é usar a Jquery e criar uma função loading.

```
function loading(status) {
if ( status == 1 )
    $('#loading').fadeIn();
else
    $('#loading').fadeOut();
```

}

E no seu iframe, definir ele com uma ID para que seja manipulado.

E por fim criar uma função pra quando estiver pronta realizar o loading:

```
$(function() { // Quando a página estiver carregada
loading(0); // Esconder o loading
```

})

Espero que tenha o ajudado.